# Benchmark Password Cracking Tools

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I want to perform a benchmark for the most popular offline password cracking tools (john the ripper and hashcat)?

What metrics or approach should i take about benchmarking in order to determine what tool is better that the other?

Comment: Are you are aware of the existing benchmarks for these 2 programs? That will give you the metrics you are looking for. Also, are you aware that they use completely different approaches?

Comment: Like: http://www.adeptus-mechanicus.com/codex/jtrhcmkv/jtrhcmkv.php

Comment: How do they use different approaches? Can you explain more on that @schroeder ?

Comment: Please do some research before posting here. Look up both tools and the approaches they use to crack hashes. Also, given the answer below, you did not notice that both tools have their own benchmarking tools.

Answer (score 3):

Both tools have a command line option to run benchmarks on your current setup:

- For John the Ripper, use `--test`.
- For hashcat, use `--benchmark` (or `-b`).